# Different model number ink

Tags: printer, printing, inkjet-printer

Can i use a different model number ink cartridge in my hp all in one? The cartridges appear to be identical in appearance and size, just different model numbers.

Comment: If you really want an answer to this you will need to provide at a minimum the model of the printer, the model of the cartridge that you are supposed to use and the one for what you want to use instead.

Answer (score 1):

No.  While they may be physically identical, modern ink cartridges have electronic interfaces with the printer that may not interface properly with a different printer than specified.